# api to get directory roles and custom roles of signed in user of Azure Ad

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have been assigned some built-in directory roles and some custom roles in Azure AD. I want to get these assigned roles when I signin my application. Which api should be called? Can someone help me out. I tried /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/appRoleAssignments api. But it is not the one which I expect to get. Is there any api like https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles/{id}/members" that gives custom roles too.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to fetch the custom role. Please use below query

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/roleManagement/directory/roleDefinitions?$filter=(isBuiltIn eq false)
```

Comment: This for getting list of custom roles. I want the list of users assigned to a particular custom role

Comment: answered to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61908762/api-to-get-list-of-users-assigned-to-a-particular-custom-role-in-azure-ad)