# api to get list of users assigned to a particular custom role in Azure AD

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I need an api that list the users assigned to a particular custom role in Azure AD or an api that gives the assigned roles, both built-in roles and custom roles of a particular user. Can anyone suggest the api. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

From the below query, you will get roledefinitionid  by giving object-id-of-principal(userID)

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/roleManagement/directory/roleAssignments?$filter=principalId eq '<object-id-of-principal>'
```

Once you receive the role definition id of a specific user you can fetch the role details(built-in and Custome role) by giving ID(roledefinitionid)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/roleManagement/directory/roleDefinitions/ID
```